# Redeclare let and const inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

We know that `let` and `const` are not hoisted.

So code like this throws an error

```
let x = 33;
let x = 99;
```

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared

Now since `let` variables are limited to the scope of a block statement, something like the following is assumed to generate the same error as the code above!

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10;) { // i here declared in this for loop block
    let i = 11; // i here is in the same for loop block
    console.log(i);
    break;
}
```

But surprisingly does not!

#### output

```
11
```

Why `let i` here is treated like it's declared in a different block? or it's like a totally different variable?

Comment: The `for (let i` in fact declares it outside of the block - though in a per-iteration scope. The `{ … }` body of the loop is a new block with its own scope.

Comment: So basically you'd need to write `for (let i=0; i<5; i++) let i;` to get the collision, but that's a syntax error for a different reason already.